# Erro ao executar servlet que consulta arquivo JAR

Tags: java, servlet

Criei um Servlet que deve acessar uma classe em java que esta em um arquivo jAR no buildpath do servlet, mas está dando um erro, vou deixar os prints aqui para quem puder me ajudar dar uma olhada. 
Obrigado!

[image: Este é o erro]

[image: Este é o código do servlet]

Comment: A linha `cep.consulta(...);` tem um *warn*, o que diz na mensagem do IDE?

Comment: diz isso: The static method consulta(String) from the type ConsultaCEP should be accessed in a 
  static way

Comment: publique o código da classe `ConsultaCEP();`!
E tente: apague a linha **31** e substitua `cep.consulta(numCep1);` por `ConsultaCEP().consulta(numCep1);`

Comment: O stackoverflow não deixa eu colocar mais :/

Comment: @MarcosSousa poderia me add em alguma rede pra me tirar algumas duvidas basicas?

Comment: @IgorSilva, posso sim. mas podemos abrir um chat, aqui pelo SOF!

Comment: @IgorSilva, comentário foi útil para sua pergunta?

Comment: Muito obrigado gente!
Na verdade nada funcionava porque o arquivo JAR foi compilado com problemas.